# Remote Desktop Connection from Window 10 to Linux (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I want to connect remotely to my workstation with Ubuntu 18 from my Windows laptop. To do so, I've tried :

- VNC - has some kind of delay, if I stream video from workstation, it will look intermittent.
- RDP (xrdp installed) - similar problem, but seems kinda faster than VNC does.
- XDMCP - failed to connect
- XPRA - I have problems to start a session. When I start it, it just becomes inaccessible

Is there a way to speed up data transfer for VNC / RPD? Is it possible to approach a response from the workstation as if it was connected to the monitor directly through video cable (HDMI, DisplayPort etc)? Is it worth trying to setup XDMCP and XPRA to check their work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Operating_system_support has a table which allows you to see which remote desktop apps provide Linux clients and Windows servers.

Answer (score 0):

xpra should work fine out of the box as long as you use the official packages from [xpra.org](https://xpra.org), the ones from the Ubuntu repositories are just too buggy.